# Throttling in Laravel

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5.6, throttling

Can somebody help me out with Laravel's Throttling ? Right now, my website uses throttling to prevent user from logging in for 'x' seconds, if the password they entered are wrong for 'x' number of time.

After logging in, user will require Two-Factor Authentication to update their information but i would like to throttle the Two-FA too, so that they will be locked out from updating their account. I can actually reuse the login's throttling codes to lock the user out but the issue is that, when the user logs out, they wont be able to log in due to the temporary lock.

I would like to create a custom throttle just for Two-FA and probably prevent the user from accessing that specific route for 'x' seconds.

I have tried searching around, but everything is related to login. If somebody could suggest me a package which will fit my requirement or provide a simple tut. will really be helpful to me. Thanks for your time.

Comment: A little broad, and I don't think you need a package since Laravel includes this functionality.  Just look at the ThrottlesLogins trait.  You can use the RateLimiter class just like they do in any controller or method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all outlined in the `ThrottlesLogins` trait, but I'll try to simplify it even further.

Generate a unique key for the user and type of request:

```
$key = '2fa:' . $user->id;
```

Add a hit (increment count) on every request to the endpoint using the `Illuminate\Cache\RateLimiter` class:

```
app(RateLimiter::class)->hit($key, $timeoutInMinutes);
```

Check if the limit has been reached before processing the request:

```
$bool = app(RateLimiter::class)->tooManyAttempts($key, $maxAttempts, $timeoutInMinutes);
```

Comment: thank you for your time and pointing out on where to look at esc 'RateLimiter'. I will give this a shot tomorrow morning and update you on how it goes. Looks promising :)